# Trying to run async and sync in series, inside foreach, gives empty result

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

So, I'm trying to run an async function and a sync operation in series, inside a `forEach`:

```
       Exchange.all().then(function (result) {
            if (!result) {
                return res.json({success: false, error: 'No exchanges records were found.'});
            }
            var exchanges = [];

            result.forEach(function (exchange) {
                var getCurrencyPairs = function (pairsResult) {
                    CurrencyPair.findAll({where: {exchangeId: exchange.id}}).then(function (pairs) {
                        var currencyPairs = [];

                        pairs.forEach(function (pair) {
                            var data = pair.dataValues;
                            currencyPairs.push({
                                baseCurrency: data.baseCurrency,
                                quoteCurrency: data.quoteCurrency,
                                marginPercentage: data.marginPercentage
                            });
                        });

                        return pairsResult(null, currencyPairs);
                    });
                };

                async.waterfall([
                    getCurrencyPairs
                ], function (err, currencyPairs) {
                    exchanges.push({
                        id: exchange.stringId,
                        name: exchange.name,
                        currencyPairs: currencyPairs,
                        depositAddress: 'sample address for now'
                    });
                    // here I have `exchanges` filled correctly after each loop iteration
                });
            });
            // here `exchanges` is completely empty
            return res.json({success: true, data: exchanges});
        });
```

Everything is working, except for `exchanges` array being empty after the `forEach` loop is finished. AFIK, `forEach` is synchronous, so I don't have to return any callback from it, and the process won't reach `return res.json()` before the `forEach` has finished, right?. Plus, inside the loop, I assign values to a global variable, which is declared outside the loop. I don't understand why the process acts like that - the global array `exchanges` is filled correctly inside the loop, but is already empty, outside it.

I thought that maybe I have to encapsulate the whole `result.forEach` inside another function, and return the result of it as a callback, but:

1. I don't understand the logic behind this being the correct solution
2. I can't imagine how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not have to redefine the getCurrencyPairs function, plus there is no need for `async.waterfall`. Then, try a recursive function, something like:

```
// Define getCurrencyPairs only once
var getCurrencyPairs = function (exchange, callback) {
   CurrencyPair.findAll({where: {exchangeId: exchange.id}}).then(function (pairs) {
       var currencyPairs = [];

       pairs.forEach(function (pair) {
          var data = pair.dataValues;
          currencyPairs.push({
              baseCurrency: data.baseCurrency,
              quoteCurrency: data.quoteCurrency,
              marginPercentage: data.marginPercentage
          });
       });

       callback(currencyPairs);
    });
};

// Start the program-logic
Exchange.all().then(function (result) {
    if (!result)
        return res.json({success: false, error: 'No exchanges records were found.'});

    var exchanges = [];
    var createExchangesObject = function(exchange){
        if(!exchange) // If there is no exchange, we obviously "poped" everything out of result and we are done
            return res.json({success: true, data: exchanges});

        getCurrencyPairs(exchange, function (currencyPairs) {
            exchanges.push({
                id: exchange.stringId,
                name: exchange.name,
                currencyPairs: currencyPairs,
                depositAddress: 'sample address for now'
            });

            // Call your selfe (recursively), with the next result
            createExchangesObject(result.pop());
         });
    }

    createExchangesObject(result.pop());
});
```

Comment: But I need to somehow pass the `exchange.id` to the `getCurrencyPairs` function... I added `exchange` argument like ` var getCurrencyPairs = function (exchange, callback) {...}` and  then inside the `create ExchangesObject function I call `getCurrencyPairs(function (exchange, currencyPairs) {...}` but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: See the latest update, i added exchange to getCurrencyPairs similar as you suggested, but wrote ```getCurrencyPairs(exchange, function (currencyPairs)``` instead of ```getCurrencyPairs(function (exchange, currencyPairs) ```. That's how it should work

Comment: Just a side question, since I'm not yet acknowledged with promises - this solution does not use any promises right? It's just a plain recursive-callback process flow? Because I get warning: `Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it` And I'd like to have a clean stack.

Comment: Ah, I see... the promise warning is at `CurrencyPair.findAll(...).then(function (pairs) {...})`, but I don't know why.